# single iteration over multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, iteration

An example of the type of multidimensional array I'd like to iterate through:

```
var myArray = [
 [id1, "john", 30],
 [id2, "smith", 60],    
 [id3, "kate", 90],
];
```

I would like to get data based on position in array using one loop.

The output should be similar to the following:

```
john is 30 
smith is 60 
kate is 90
```

Comment: What's your expected output in the console?

Comment: `["john", 30],
 ["smith", 60],    
 ["kate", 90]` ?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use an array of objects instead? Then you could reference each property by it's name instead of index number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just iterate to get a reference for placement in the array and then hardcode values into the code regarding values inside that reference.

```
var myArray = [
 ["john", 30],
 ["smith", 60],    
 ["kate", 90],
];

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${myArray[i][0]} is ${myArray[i][1]}`)
}
```

If you want to get them in the same line, use a string.

```
var myArray = [
 ["john", 30],
 ["smith", 60],    
 ["kate", 90],
];

let str = ''
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  str += `${myArray[i][0]} is ${myArray[i][1]} `
}
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Map through the array and insert the values into the string:

```js
var myArray = [
 [1, "john", 30],
 [2, "smith", 60],    
 [3, "kate", 90],
];

const res = myArray.map(e => `${e[1]} is ${e[2]}`).join('\n')
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to solve this is by using map

```
myArray.map(person => `${person[1]} is ${person[2]}`)
```

Comment: `flatMap` is redundant. Just use `map`